# Android Kinvey java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, kinvey

I have an android application that used kinvey and it worked just fine with me suddenly i got

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

so i put

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

in my gradle file but then i got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`  in the line when i create new client

```
mKinveyClient = new Client.Builder(AP_ID,App_Secret, this).build();
```

i tried to clean project ,clean gradle file , updated my kinvey sdk from 1.5 to 1.6 Any suggestions?

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    dexOptions { //for the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }       

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.augmentedreality"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('src/main/java/Vuforia.jar')
    compile(name:'kinvey-android-2.10.6', ext:'aar') {changing= true}
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.gordonwong:material-sheet-fab:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    ///////////////////////////for animating the text
    ///////////////////////
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    ///////////////google cloud messaging
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Edit:in the image below my jars files

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using Android Studio, do you see the Kinvey libraries when you expand the "External Libraries" in the project pane?

Comment: the jars file are in the image is there any thing wrong with it ?

Comment: Can you show the full `build.gradle` please?

Comment: You are getting an out of memory because you have included **all** the Google play services with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`. You can split them up according to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project). If you just want cloud messaging, then you want `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you copied both the kinvey JAR file and the AAR file into the `libs/` folder. You only need the AAR.

The class that is claimed to be missing, `com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser`, is contained within `google-http-client-1.19-0.jar`, so adding that JAR file to the correct `libs/` directory in the  module and including these lines in you `build.gradle` should properly find that class without error.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {    
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'kinvey-android-*', ext:'aar')

    // other stuff
}
```

---

With regards to the OutOfMemory error, you most likely exceeded the [Android Dex method limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) because of how many dependencies you've included. Most specifically, the last line of your gradle file for the `play-services` dependency. If you read [that documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), you'll see the note that says

> **Note**: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

Since you seem to only want cloud messaging, you can just include that one, so replace this line.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

With this one

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

And any [other Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) you want to include.

Comment: when i changed the line of Google play service it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> i got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

You have included wrong Dependant jar. Add appropriate Dependant version of jar by using maven or gradle.

Comment: That's obviously the problem... If you included what jar was needed, then this answer would be useful.

Comment: i have followed this link http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/getting-started i donnt know which jar files are wrong can you tell me please ?